# Why can't I send/receive emails from AWS Ubuntu using Postfix?

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm trying to send/receive emails on my AWS Ubuntu box.
To do so, I'm following the instructions posted by Amazon [**here**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/postfix.html). (I skipped the section entitled **"To configure integration using a secure tunnel"**)

However, I'm still unable to send any emails. When I try to send an email to `my.user@gmail.com`, it fails:

```
local_user@ip-172-XXX-XXX-XXX:~$ netcat mydomain.com 25
220 mydomain.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
ehlo mydomain.com
250-mydomain.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
mail from: root@mydomain.com
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to: my.user@gmail.com
454 4.7.1 <my.user@gmail.com>: Relay access denied
```

Here is what log file shows:

```
$ sudo tail -F /var/log/mail.log
Oct 17 18:06:10 ip-172-XXX-XXX-XXX postfix/smtpd[22869]: warning: hostname ec2-54-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com does not resolve to address 54.XXX.XXX.XXX
Oct 17 18:06:10 ip-172-XXX-XXX-XXX postfix/smtpd[22869]: connect from unknown[54.XXX.XXX.XXX]
Oct 17 18:06:31 ip-172-XXX-XXX-XXX postfix/smtpd[22869]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[54.XXX.XXX.XXX]: 454 4.7.1 <my.user@gmail.com>: Relay access denied; from=<root@mydomain.com> to=<my.user@gmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mydomain.com>
```

How can I fix this? What is the problem? Please note that my EC2 is in AWS's `US West (Oregon)` region. But I have set the relay host to `email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:25` in the `main.cf` file. Is that the issue? I don't think it is.

**My main.cf file is posted [here](https://gist.github.com/syedsaqibali/452dd6d814d426b12040)**

Comment: Forgot to authenticate?

Comment: Sebix, could you please elaborate what you mean and how I should fix it?

Answer (score 3):

You've got a typo on your relayhost.

```
relayhost = email-smtp.us-east.amazonaws.com:25
```

should be

```
relayhost = email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:25
```

Comment: I fixed my main.cf: https://gist.github.com/syedsaqibali/ddd5ec91665b9b20f42b

But the problem persists just the same.

Comment: Did you restart the service?  Also make sure your username & password are the gibberish-looking ones, (made up examples: AIAIIAAAKKKIAAL and the longer AOAOOAAALALALLALJD/AALSLLS8772), not an IAM username & password that you might have named & set a password for.

Comment: Yes. I restarted the service by doing this: `sudo /etc/init.d/postfix restart`. And my sasl_passwd file looks like this: **mail-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:25 ASADSGG77G65HH4I8U5A:AdYjKUrwf/K40/YsJ57/wPYTESfhHTqwsBnnYUIpoyt7** (I have munged it. But that's kinda what it looks like. I got the creds from AWS.)

Comment: ...I can't reply to the other answer under @sebix because my rep is too low...but if you followed the amazon config doc, you set up the sasl auth....

There's a footnote on that doc, you may need to add this line to /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd:
    ses-smtp-prod-335357831.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com:25 USERNAME:PASSWORD

Comment: here's the link to the doc...go all the way to the bottom:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-issues.html

Comment: I **replaced** the entry in my sasl_passwd file with this: `ses-smtp-us-west-2-prod-14896026.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com:25 USERNAME:PASSWORD`. Then I did `sudo postmap hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` and `sudo /etc/init.d/postfix restart`. Same issue. Do I have to use this relayserver in my main.cf file as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17962/discussion-between-saqib-ali-and-trackzero).

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. Mailservers accept for unauthenticated incoming connections only mails to local users. For authenticated users, this restriction is not valid (see your `permit_sasl_authenticated` in `smtpd_relay_restrictions`) and thus these users are allowed to relay mails (the mailserver delivers to the internet).

To allow a specific host without authentication, add it to the `mynetworks` parameter.

---

You are btw missing commas between the values of `smtpd_relay_restrictions`.

Comment: Thanks. I added the commas. When you say "To allow a specific host without authentication", does this mean the host I'm trying to send to (gmail.com)? Currently, my mynetworks setting is this: `mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128`. What should I change it to?

Comment: That depends on what you want. If you have some servers other servers running applications that send mails through this mailserver, put their IPs in `mynetworks`. If you want to allow some users using mailclients to send mails, use autentication. However, I recommend some basic knowledge of networking, SMTP and server administration in general before running a mailserver facing the public net!

Comment: I just want to automatically forward all emails that are sent to my.user@mydomain.com to my.user@gmail.com. But I guess I need it to be working through AWS SES.

Comment: The problem description you gave in the question does not a bit match your new description of forwarding everything to gmail. Please search the net on how to do this. I won't put any further effort in answering/commenting this topic.